# Draft.js editor appends highlighted words to end of string for one state update if typed back to back (CodeSandbox attached)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, draftjs, codesandbox

I'm attempting to create a editor with Draft.js which will highlight specific words as the user types them, however I've been running into a bug where **if the same highlighted word is typed back to back separated by a single space** it will cause the highlighted substring to be appended to the end of the previous editor content for one state update (content returns to expected value upon the next editor state update).

I have found that in `findWithRegex()`, if I set `end` the match array length +/- 1 `e.g. end = start + matchArr[0].length + 1;` it resolves the issue, it seems to be something with setting `end` to the exact length of the substring.

**CodeSandbox**: https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-thunder-fp2rx8?file=/src/App.tsx (**"doe" is the highlight word in this example**)

I'm writing this at 1 AM so I hope my issue makes sense haha, please ask any questions you might have. Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you are writing this at 1AM - please go to bed, sleep well and try again in the morning :) usually one gets better ideas after a nap :)

Comment: @Deian haha feeling refreshed and ready to attack it again ;) I've been working on this bug for a couple days now though haha

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, it seems to be a conflict with React Strict Mode haha. All I had to do was remove the `<React.StrictMode>` tags in my `index.js/index.tsx` file and now everything works as intended